# How to fix System.ArgumentException by Transform a Graphic with Windows Forms (C++/CLI)?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I am a beginner with C++ and in order to learn graphic programming we learn C++/CLI with WindowsForms (VisualStudio 2017).

My task is it to draw a train by push button "zeichnen" and to transform the train to an other position on the windows.

I would have liked to even change the position of the wheels but at the moment I am unable do even change the position to let the train drive forward on screen x,y(50,0).

I did look in the .net Framework-Api from Windows. 
There I found the Method: System.Drawing.Graphics.SetClip(Rectangle rect);
I thought that I would cout out the old drawing and translate this, but I only get Wrong Parameter Errors.

The same is if I try to use the Method Transform.

Sure I could copy the first drawing to the new Method. But I can not imagine that this is in any way good programming. Even if I change the parameter. 
But I did try... the effect was that I got the old Train-Image and above this one was the new Train-Image x+50. This really was not what I did try to do.

I do not understand how to change that position of the drawing.

MyForm.h -> gernereatet WindowsForm
namespace Zeichnen

```
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form{
    private: 
    System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnZeichnen;
    System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnFahre;
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
    Graphics ^ pg;
private: 
System::Void btnZeichnen_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
System::Void btnFahre_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
};
/*everything else is automatic generated*/
}
```

MyForm.cpp (my Code)
The First Button, without a problem:

```
   System::Void Zeichnen::MyForm::btnZeichnen_Click(System::Object ^ sender, System::EventArgs ^ e){
pg = CreateGraphics();
/*Create Variables and Draw all parts of the Train e.g.*/
    pg->FillRectangle(sb_dkgray, x_btop, y_btop, w_btop, h_btop);
delete pg;
}
```

The Second Button - with Problem:

```
    System::Void Zeichnen::MyForm::btnFahre_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
pg->SetClip(Rectangle(0,0,1000,550));
int dx = 50;
pg->TranslateClip(dx, 0);
     }
```

I get the train by click on the button "Zeichnen". But I get the failure by the button "fahre"

Informationen über das Aufrufen von JIT-Debuggen
anstelle dieses Dialogfelds finden Sie am Ende dieser Meldung.

```
    ************** Ausnahmetext **************
    System.ArgumentException: Ungültiger Parameter.
       bei System.Drawing.Graphics.SetClip(Rectangle rect, CombineMode combineMode)
       bei System.Drawing.Graphics.SetClip(Rectangle rect)
       bei Zeichnen.MyForm.btnFahre_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in         c:\users\michi\dropbox\alfatraining\c++\cli\04-        26\zeichnen\zeichnen\myform.cpp:Zeile 118.
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       bei System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I do know that I make a mistake. Somehow I need to save the last position. And than I will need to change the position. But everything I try does only frustrate me more. Since it is everytime the same failure. There are overloading methods. But is says there are wrong parameter or not enough.

I do not understand why it calls: System.Drawing.Graphics.SetClip(Rectangle rect, CombineMode combineMode), even if I want to call: System.Drawing.Graphics.SetClip(Rectangle rect)

I did even try to make a matrix but even this didn't go anywhere right. At the moment I am only frustrated since I tried to find the correct answer myself the last two days... but it seems I can't find any tutorial that works anywhere like my program or want to do something alike.

Comment: This: `Graphics ^ pg;` is the mistake. From that point on, everything is wrong. See the simple examples in the Docs, especially how and where the Graphics object is used: [Graphics.TranslateClip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.translateclip?view=netframework-4.8) and the related methods. Don't try to store Graphics objects.

Comment: At the lesson we did use Graphics ^ pg = CreateGraphics(); in the first method. I think there I will need it. 

So I do everything wrong in the last methode.... but

e->Graphics->SetClip this is not possible. 

Okay in the Api e is an Object from PaintEventArgs where the e in my method is from EventArgs ... 0

I really do not understand how this will work.

Comment: The first call to `CreateGraphics();` works because you just created it: `pg = CreateGraphics(); pg->FillRectangle(...)`. The graphics object is still valid there (not persistent but valid).  But this is not the point. You cannot store this object. You can try to create and destroy it in-place, even though it will not persist. But this is not the way painting in WinForms works. Use the Paint event or override OnPaint: `protected: virtual void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs^ e ) override`. The provided `e->Graphics` object is what you want.

Comment: Okay... i did see this override method in some C# tutorials ... but I did not understand how it is used. They write an overwrite but don't call the method? It is really irritating and useless to copy something you do not understand.

Okay my last try was overkill...
System::Void btnFahre_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e); 

Now I there is something is wrong with the delegate ... 

I do not know what delegate really means. @_@ 

I really do not see what I need to do. Is there some tutorial for dummys?

Comment: See the example I linked before. You cannot tamper with the event delegate that way. See the Docs. It's quite simple once you get the hang of it. Btw, you don't call `OnPaint`, you just override it.

Comment: I did read the linked example but I seems to not understand it the way I need to. I do not see what I need to do. 

Here the Tutorial i found: https://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=21782 

It is with C# but since it used the same Api it should work. But ... I can say I understand much...

Soo... I wrote the SetClip Part into OnPaint but it does nothing? I really do not know what to do. 

ARGH ... I really do not understand anything I need to find a tutorial that I can follow.

I only want to cry out from frustration. But this I can't to because it'll wake up the kid. T_T

Comment: You can follow that example. Not great, but i'ts more or less the same thing in C++/CLI. Note that this: `Graphics g;` in the `OnPaint` override is just to avoid writing `e.Graphics.Something();` and instead just write `g.Something()`. Pretty useless but shorter; many perform this assignment (you don't dispose of `g`, it's the same reference as `e.Graphics`, it's handled internally). My personal suggestion: take a break :) Tomorrow will be better (maybe) :)